# Dispose cache from multiple web role instances from azure application

Tags: azure, caching

i am having a problem related to the cache disposal in azure cloud application.
i am using MVC3 structure, using 2 instances.

as we know that the Microsoft azure automatically allocates a web role to serve a web request based on load balancing.

but the problem is that when i dispose a cache "HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("CacheName")", it is disposed of from the current web role that i am currently alloted by microsoft.
and doesnt dispose the cache from the other instance.

please help me, can i dispose a cache from the two instance a the same time?
using any C# sharp code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good reason to use a distributed cache.  Synchronizing cache adds and removes individually across many instances and caches is hard to do well.  Any code or solution that attempts to solve the issue will be pretty hacky.  Moving the caching out to a distributed cache will solve the problem for you correctly.

Have you looked at the Windows Azure AppFabric Caching solution?

Comment: also, i have a work around using a service contract. using the TCP endpoint in the web role. sime code you just have to adda endpoint (tcp) and then create a [ServiceContractAttribute] class interface class like

Comment: [ServiceContractAttribute]
    public interface ICDMMessage
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void CacheCDM(string host, string AccId, string Db, string LangID);
    }

and a


    public class CDMMessage : ICDMMessage 
    {
        public void CacheCDM(string host, string AccId, string Db, string LangID)
        {
            CDM cdm = CDM.GetInstance();
            cdm.CacheCDMOnALL(host, AccId, Db, LangID);
        }
    }

Comment: and in your normal public class call a fucntion like

                var current = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance;
                var instances = current.Role.Instances;
                foreach (RoleInstance instance in instances)
                {
                    if (instance.Id != current.Id)
                    {

                          client.CacheCDM(host, AccId, Db, LangID);
                        flag =  "True";
}

Comment: @Hisham, can you put your comments into an answer?

Comment: However, you really should be looking to use AppFabric as @dunnry said

Comment: If you have something like translations you rally want them close ... so a distributed cache is not an option.